# Isotope element dynamic height

Tags: jquery, tumblr, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope on my tumblr theme, but my post (which is an isotope-item) - on a permalink page - will not increase its height after loading more notes. These notes are dynamically inserted after one clicks a link. I've found a possible solution to this by calling `.isotope('reLayout');` but it seems I can't get it to work. It will load the new notes, but they get cut off by their container which doesn't increase height at all.

I tried doing it with a click event on the 'show more notes' link, but that link already has inline javascript being executed on click. How can I have the isotope item increase its height (by executing `.isotope('reLayout');`) on the click of the 'show more notes' link?

Here's the default tumblr code:

```
<li class="note more_notes_link_container" style="text-align:center;" id="more_notes_59995759535">
            <a class="more_notes_link" rel="nofollow" href="#" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('notes_loading_59995759535').style.display = 'block';if(window.ActiveXObject)var tumblrReq=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');else if(window.XMLHttpRequest)var tumblrReq=new XMLHttpRequest();else return false;tumblrReq.onreadystatechange=function(){if(tumblrReq.readyState==4){var notes_html=tumblrReq.responseText.split('<!-- START '+'NOTES -->')[1].split('<!-- END '+'NOTES -->')[0];
if(window.tumblrNotesLoaded)if(tumblrNotesLoaded(notes_html)==false)return;var more_notes_link=document.getElementById('more_notes_59995759535');var notes=more_notes_link.parentNode;notes.removeChild(more_notes_link);notes.innerHTML+=notes_html;if(window.tumblrNotesInserted)tumblrNotesInserted(notes_html);}};tumblrReq.open('GET','/notes/59995759535/YbpaUsPSt?from_c=1378154277',true);tumblrReq.send();return false;">Show more notes</a><span class="notes_loading" id="notes_loading_59995759535" style="display:none;">Loading...</span>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a fiddle for you ..

`if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))`

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/ub3UD/100/)**

Hope this helps you

OK I have a link for you .. Just go through it maybe helpful [**link**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html#content)

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer. I forgot to mention I'm a javascript/jquery noob and I can't see how this can solve my issue. If you could, please give me some more directions on how I would implement this into my tumblr theme. I think the inline javascript that tumblr adds by default on the 'load more notes' link prevents me from executing any other javascript on the same click event on that link.

Comment: @user1145009 Just have a look at my updated answer with a link

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not an issue with isotope, but with tumblr/javascript here. The inline javascript on the onclick event prevents any other javascript to be executed. I tried triggering an alert but even that didn't work. `$('.more_notes_link').click() { alert('success') };`
So I guess I'm looking for a solution to execute isotope's reLayout function *in addition* to the default inline javascript on the same click event...

Comment: I got it to work somehow, but only for the first click:

`$('.more_notes_link').click(function(){
            alert('hi');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        });`

this will trigger the alert dialog. Once I dismiss the dialog, the reLayout is triggered and increases the height of the container as intended. But it only does so on the first click of the link. How can I make it work (do the reLayout) on each click? Oh, and without the alert, it won't work at all. So a solution for that would be nice too.